# Huge Django project

Tags: python, django

I have a new job and a huge django project (15 apps, more than 30 loc). It's pretty hard to understand it's architecture from scratch. Are there any techniques to simplify my work in the beginning? sometimes it's even hard to understand where to find a form or a view that I need... thnx in advance.

Comment: 30 loc is huge? Even 30Kloc is not huge...

Comment: Personally , I think start with setting.py and url.py is a good starting point

Comment: Get a good IDE like Wing that can help you "go to definition" making it easy to find where things are.   Luckily it's a Django project and not PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I come to this kind of problem I open up a notebook and answer the following:

**1. Infrastructure**

- Server configuration, OS etc
- Check out the database type (mysql, postgres, nosql)
- External APIS (e.g Facebook Connect)

**2. Backend**

- Write a simple description
- Write its input/output from user (try to be thorough; which fields are required and which aren't)
- Write its FK and its relation to any other apps (and why)
- List down each plugin the app is using. And for what purpose. For example in rails I'd write: 'gem will_paginate - To display guestbook app results on several pages'

**3. Frontend**

- Check out the JS framework
- Check the main stylesheet files (for the template)
- The main html/haml (etc) files for creating a new template based page.

When you are done doing that. I think you are much more prepared and able go deeper developing/debugging the app. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use this http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/graph_models.html

to generate the Relationship diagrams from the models so that you can visually see how the models are related to each other. This will give you nice idea about the app

Answer (score 2):

1) Try to install the site from scratch. You will find what external apps are needed for the site to run.

2) Reverse engineer. Browse through the site and try to find out what you have to do to change something to that page. Start with the url, look up in urls.py, read the view, check the model. Are there any hints to other processes?

3) Try to write down everything you don't understand, and document the answers for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

I would clone the project so you can mess up endlessly.

Then I would start to reduce the code. "What happens if if just remove this function here?

Also get django debug toolbar:

https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar

A good terminal debugger is also golden, there are many out there, here is an example:

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-pdb

This allow you to halt the code and even inject and mutate parameters in runtime. Just like GDB in C.

Comment: Removing functions isn't so good if you don't have unittests.  If the project has good test coverage, reading the tests can be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use FireFox you can install FireBug on it and when you for example submit ajax form you can see at which url send you request after what you can easily find controller which work with this form data. At chrome this utility embedded by default and call by F12 key.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down, this can be handy to know, if you don't.